# Efficiently count distant value in millions rows in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to count how many account has `Banana`. And I only care the total number of accounts

Takes the following data as an example (real data could has millions of entries):

| Account | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | Apple, Orange, Banana, Pear |
| BBB | Apple |
| AAA | Apple, Orange |
| AAA | Banana, Pear |
| AAA | Banana |
| CCC | Banana |

The expected result will be: 2 (Both AAA and CCC has Banana)

And here is my working but slow query:

```
[{
    $match: {
        'Fruit': 'Banana'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "Account": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "uniqueAccount": {
            $addToSet: "$Account"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "FinalAccountCounts": {
            $size: "$uniqueAccount"
        }
    }
}]
```

Can someone help me to improve the performance of above query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
[{
    $match: {
        'Fruit': 'Banana'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "Account": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$Account",
        
    }
}, {
    $count: "FinalAccountCounts"
       
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it's only 3min faster than the original query (from 74min to 71min)

Comment: can i know whats the result of FinalAccountCounts?

Comment: The result of `FinalAccountCounts` is just as expected and correct. But the improvement is minor. I think your query might be the optimal one (or very close to optimal)

Comment: I know I want to know number of docs has been grouped

Comment: In real data, the total document count is about 6.5M and the `FinalAccountCounts` is about 20,000. (btw, it runs on rather low spec machine)

Comment: It runs once a day

Comment: It has 25 fields. And the `Fruit` field is a list, it normally has 1 to 5 items.